# How do I scale an object proportionally using numbers on the scale panel?

Tags: objects

Everytime I change the X axis to 2' it literally only does the x axis and I was wondering if there was a way I could do this proportionally

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? What do you mean by proportionally?

Answer (score 8):

By **left-clicking** and **dragging down** on the sliders you can select and edit the values for multiple axes simultaneously:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to do things with keyboard shortcuts you can press **<kbd>S</kbd>** and drag, that will scale your object (or selected vertices, depending on what mode you are on) in all axes.

To constrain transformations on a single axis you can do **<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>** to scale on the **X** axis only, or **<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>** to scale on **X** and **Y** only (but not on **Z**)

Comment: That isn't quite working when I tried it actually, I left clicked them all and since I'm preparing this object for a 3D print I tried inputting 3 inches on the x and I noticed that it changed x y and z. I'm more looking for a way to edit one axis and let the computer calculate the rest so it is still proportional to what it was originally just downscaled.

Comment: This was added in 2.70 and you need to drag straight down for it to work, if you go sideways a bit it starts changing the value.